# htaccess issue not working properly

Tags: .htaccess

I am using URL Rewriting in .htaccess file my problem is this in root folder I have index.php file and I am redirect to `en/home/` folder but redirection is not working when I use this .htaccess code.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*+)$ en/peoples/globalCardDetail.php?p=$1
```

Rewriting is working fine like this `http://www.domain.com/atiq ur rehman`. But when I access my domain `http://www.domain.com` this is redirecting to this page `en/peoples/globalCardDetail.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your regular expression from `^([^/]*+)$` to `^([^/]+)$`.

Also, you may want to add some conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ en/peoples/globalCardDetail.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: redirection is not working same problem showing this file en/peoples/globalCardDetail.php

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ en/peoples/globalCardDetail.php?p=$1 [L]
This code was helpfull